# Setting the default directory where screenshots are saved

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

I am writing a utility that changes the directory where the Mac OS X saves the screenshots taken when pressing the shortcuts listen in the Keyboard preference panel. Where should that value be saved, to be used from the Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screencapture.plist` under the key `location`. Source: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050824073301844